# Ember build output (dist folder)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In Ember JS project, we have package.json (for NPM managed) and bower.json (Bower managed) where we have all our dependencies/devDependencies (e.g. bootstrap, jquery, ember, etc)

Now these get downloaded from their respective registries and get downloaded locally into node_modules/bower_components folder.

Now my question is while these folders (node_modules/bower_components) contain a lot of code dependencies, when we do a build, I see some code in the "dist" folder.
I want to understand what actually goes into this dist ?
I see things like vendor.css, vendor.js, myappName.css, myappName.js, etc

So how do these get constructed and what code actually goes inside these ?
Is it also base on what we have in our package/bower json config files ?
Or is it based on what we have in ember-cli-build.js ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is put under `/dist` should be everything you need to publish your application. Components from `bower_components` are typically loaded via `app.import()` in `ember-cli-build.js` and stuff from `node_modules` by addons you've installed (which ember-cli picks up automatically).

Here is a quick rundown of the files.

```
index.html --> Generated by ember-cli upon project creation
*          --> Everything from /public
assets/
    appName.css --> All css from under /app
    appName.js  --> All js and compiled templates from /app
    vendor.css  --> Any css imported from bower_components/node_modules (via ember-cli-build.js)
    vendor.js   --> Any js imported from bower_components/node_modules (via ember-cli-build.js)
    test-*.js   --> Test loader/support for ember-cli if you've run "ember test"
```

Most files also come with sourcemaps as `.map` which you can exclude when publishing the site.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the dependencies you declare in your bower.json and package.json get downloaded to `bower_components` and `node_modules`

When you do you an `ember build` command what happens is that all the code you decide to import in your `ember-cli-build.js` will get dumped to the `vendor.js` / `vendor.css` file. All your application code (templates/routes/components/controllers/services) will be placed in `my-app-name.js`. All your application styles will go to the `my-app-name.css` file. All these files will be placed in the `dist` directory so that you can deploy it.

See this sample `ember-cli-build.js` file:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
 //CSS - Content of these files will go to "vendor.css"
 app.import('vendor/css/bootstrap.css');
 app.import('bower_components/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css');
 app.import('bower_components/datatables/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css');
 app.import('vendor/css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css');

 // Javascript - Content of these files will go to "vendor.js"
 app.import('vendor/js/bootstrap.js');
 app.import('vendor/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js');
 app.import('vendor/js/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js');
 app.import('bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js');

 return app.toTree();
};
```

The CSS imports will go to the `vendor.css` file and the JS imports will go to the `vendor.js` files.

The content of your `my-app-name.css` comes from the `app/styles` folder.

If you do `ember build --environment production` the ember build process will also fingertring your assets (append a hash at the end of the filename and generate an appropriate reference in the index.html file).

Comment: Thx a lot...In the ember-cli-build, you have shown imports for bower_components...how does it happen for those under node_modules ?

Comment: I've never done that actually, but I believe that it works the exact same way. The problem you might run into is that some npm modules might not be made to work in the browser and those will probably break your application. 

I've seem people recommend ember-browserify (https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify) to be able to import some npm modules into an ember app.

Comment: Just one more quetsion...while doing import using bower_components, it is clear where it looks up for the source (i.e. under myapp/bower_components/...)

However, it is not clear where those with vendor looks up for the source ? I mean it starts from which folder to copy the code ?

Comment: For vendor is the same. It looks in `myapp/vendor` (you should have that folder created automatically when creating a new ember-cli project). In my vendor folder, I created the subfolders `js/plugins/toasts`, `vendor/js/plugins/metisMenu/`, etc..  and put those files there, but the vendor folder is a default one.

Comment: Hmm...i do not see vendor under myApp folder (even though I generated it via ember-cli)...not sure if it is specific to some version.. Also do you copy only those files under vendor which you need to be copied in the build output ?

Comment: That's weird, according to the [documentation](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#folder-layout) you should have that folder.

In the `vendor` folder I place the files that are not managed by bower.

Comment: It says "Your external dependencies not installed with Bower or npm." ...so i assume files have to be manually dropped for vendor

Comment: Yup, exactly. Sorry for not making that explicit.